# Capturing POST data

Tags: plugins, posts, plugin-development, ajax, forms

I am trying to modify the [Member Status Plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/member-status/) so that the status are based on the data saved on a custom database table.

Basically I wanted to change the administration menu with a form that can manually update the data saved in the database.

I noticed the current form is pointing to /wp-admin/options.php but im very new to WP (2 days) and not sure why it is so.

How can I direct the form to pass it to the plugin instead so I can update the data on the table?

I am assuming once I can do that I can only use AJAX to do the same thing, am I right on this?

Answer (score 0):

It points to `options.php` because it uses the [Settings API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_API). Well, not completely, but that’s not the point now. You should not change that.

What you can do, to add your own logic: hook into the save process for that option:

```
add_filter( "sanitize_option_webweb-member-status-group", "your_extra_handler" );

function your_extra_handler( $input )
{
    if ( isset ( $_POST['your_extra_post_field'] ) )
        // do something awesome

    return $input; // don’t touch that value
}
```